# Динамическое изменение цвета объектов в SVG

Tags: svg, анимация

Есть вот такая картинка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите можно ли такую же сдать при помощи SVG и сделать так что бы  круги плавно меняли цвет? Вот что у меня получилось

```
 <svg width="120" height="120"  viewBox="0 0 120 120"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >

    <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="50">
        <animate attributeName="fill" 
                      attributeType="XML"
                      values="#9a5aa3;#0054a4;#c3996b;#d81a5b;#f69542"
                      dur="5.9s"
                      repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </circle>
</svg>
 <svg width="120" height="120"  viewBox="0 0 120 120"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >

    <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="50">
        <animate attributeName="fill" 
                      attributeType="XML"
                      values="#9a5aa3;#0054a4;#c3996b;#d81a5b;#f69542"
                      dur="5.9s"
                      repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </circle>
</svg>
 <svg width="120" height="120"  viewBox="0 0 120 120"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >

    <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="50">
        <animate attributeName="fill" 
                      attributeType="XML"
                      values="#f69542;#0054a4;#c3996b;#d81a5b;#9a5aa3"
                      dur="5.9s"
                      repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </circle>
</svg>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pLh05ypL/89/

Comment: Используй css-анимацию для цвета.

Comment: С анимацией я разобрался осталось автоматически заполнить шар кругами при помощи SVG

Comment: Он и на приведённой картинке неверно заполнен - как будто полюсы острые.

Comment: Приведенная картинка просто нарисована в фотошопе а мне надо такую же сделать при помощи SVG

Comment: Перерисуй её в иллюстраторе и экспортируй в svg?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Слой_1" xmlns:x="&ns_extend;" xmlns:i="&ns_ai;" xmlns:graph="&ns_graphs;"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 595.3 841.9"
  style="enable-background:new 0 0 595.3 841.9;" xml:space="preserve">


<linearGradient id="SVGID_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0.7071" y2="0.7071">
 <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#E6E6EB"/>
 <stop  offset="0.1738" style="stop-color:#E2E2E6"/>
 <stop  offset="0.352" style="stop-color:#D5D4D8"/>
 <stop  offset="0.5323" style="stop-color:#C0BFC2"/>
 <stop  offset="0.7139" style="stop-color:#A4A2A4"/>
 <stop  offset="0.8949" style="stop-color:#828282"/>
 <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#6B6E6E"/>
</linearGradient>
<g id="XMLID_4_">
 <path id="XMLID_2491_" class="st0" d="M70.7,326.9c-3,7.6-5.8,15.1-8.9,22.7c-1,2.5-2.6,4.8-3.9,7.3c-0.5,1.5-1.6,2-3,1.7
  c-1.4-0.4-1.6-1.4-1-2.7c-1-9.9,2.8-19,5.1-28.3c2.6-10.4,7-20.3,10.5-30.4c0.5-1.5,1.7-2.7,2.6-4.1c0.8-1.4,1.6-3,3.7-2.3
  c1.6,0.6,2.1,2,2.4,3.4c0.7,4-0.8,7.7-1,11.6c-1.1,5.5-2.5,11-3.9,16.5C72.8,324,72.5,325.8,70.7,326.9z"/>
 <path id="XMLID_2490_" class="st1" d="M50.8,413c1.2-2.4,2.6-1.7,3.6,0c1.1,1.8,2.2,3.8,2.9,5.8c5.9,17.5,9.6,35.3,8.7,53.8
  c-0.1,2.1,0.7,6.5-4.1,3.4c-1.3-0.7-1.6-2.4-2.8-3.1c-2.2-9.8-4.3-19.6-6.6-29.4c-0.5-2.1-0.5-4.2-0.5-6.4c-1-1.6,0.1-3.5-0.9-5.1
  c-0.3-2.4-1.7-4.6-0.9-7c0.5-3.2,0.6-6.4-0.3-9.5C49.4,414.4,50,413.6,50.8,413z"/>
 <path id="XMLID_2487_" class="st2" d="M109.8,242.9c-2.1,1.4-4,2.9-6.2,4c-1.2,0.6-2.7,0.3-1.6-1.8c0.4-2.3,1.7-4.2,2.9-6.1
  c7.3-10.7,16.1-20.2,25.7-28.9c2.6-0.5,3.5-3.3,5.7-4.3c0.8-0.7,1.6-1.6,2.9-1.4c1.3,0,4.3-2.8,2.9,1.7c-0.5,1.6-1,3.1-2,4.5
  c-0.2,0.4-0.4,0.7-0.7,1c-0.8,0.9-1.4,2-2.8,2.3c-0.5,0.7-1.1,1.3-1.6,2c-0.8,1.6-1.9,3-3.3,4.1c-0.6,0.6-1.1,1.3-1.7,1.9
  c-1,2-2.7,3.5-4.3,5.1c-0.6,0.6-1.1,1.2-1.7,1.9c-2.1,3.8-5.9,6.1-8.3,9.7C113.8,240.1,112.4,242.3,109.8,242.9z"/>
 <path id="XMLID_2486_" class="st3" d="M462.7,588.1c0.8-0.4,1.7-0.7,2.5-1.1c1,1.6-0.5,2.8-0.8,4.7c4.6-1.6,7.2-6,11.7-7.3
  c1.4,0.2,2.2,1,2.5,2.3c-0.1,2.7-2.4,4-3.9,5.7c-0.4,0.6-1.3,0.9-1.3,1.8c0,0,0.6,0,0.9,0c1.4,0.4,3.7-0.9,3.8,2
  c-4.4,4.7-9.5,8.4-14.7,11.9c-0.8,0.4-1.3,0-1.8-0.6c-0.2-0.4-0.2-0.9-0.1-1.3c0.4-1.2,1.5-1.7,2.3-2.4c-0.1,0,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1
  s-0.3,0.2-0.4,0.2c-0.8,0.7-1.7,1-2.7,0.8c-0.7-0.2-1.1-0.6-1.4-1.3c-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.8,0-1.2c0.1-0.3,0.2-0.5,0.3-0.8
  c-0.3,0-0.5,0.2-0.7,0.5c-1.7,1.2-3.4,2.4-4.4,4.3c-1.1,1.1,0,2.4-0.3,3.6c-1.7,2.7-4.4,3.7-7.4,4.1c-1-0.1-1.9-0.4-2.4-1.4
  c-0.4-2.7,2.7-3.5,3.1-6.3c-2.8-0.5-5.1,2.1-7.8,1.5c-0.7-0.3-1.2-0.7-1.4-1.5c1.4-4.5,5.5-6.3,9-8.7c1.3-0.2,2.5,0.9,3.8,0.4
  C456.1,595.8,458.9,591.4,462.7,588.1z"/>
 <path id="XMLID_2485_" class="st4" d="M88.2,532.7c-0.3-2.6,0.7-3.7,2.9-1.9c2.3,1.9,4.4,4,6.4,6.2c7,7.7,12.6,16.5,18.2,25.2
  c1.9,0.9,2.5,2.9,3.6,4.5c0.2,0.4,0.3,0.9,0.3,1.3c0,1.4,0.3,3-1.5,3.7c-1.3,0.4-2.5,0-3.5-0.8c-0.5,0.1-0.7-0.1-0.6-0.6
  c-1.1-1.9-3.1-3.1-4.3-5c-1.3-1.8-3.2-3-4.1-5.1c-1.3-1.8-3.1-3.1-4.1-5.1c-1.1-1.4-2.3-2.7-3.3-4.2c-0.4-0.6-0.8-1.1-1.2-1.7
  c-1-2.1-2.8-3.5-4-5.5l0-0.4c-0.6-1.5-1.8-2.7-2.5-4.2C89.2,537.2,88.5,535,88.2,532.7z"/>
 <path id="XMLID_2484_" class="st5" d="M461.9,606.8c0.5,0.5,1,0.9,1.5,1.4c-17.5,13.9-37,24.3-57.5,32.7
  c-11.5,4.7-23.3,8.9-35.6,11.2c-1.1,0.5-2.1,0.6-2.5-0.9c1.3-3,4.4-2.6,6.7-3.4c1.7-0.6,3.5-1,5.2-1.6c4.2-1.2,8.4-2.8,12.6-4.1
  c1.3-0.4,2.7-0.8,4-1.2c1.1-0.3,2.1-0.7,3.2-1c0.6-0.2,1.2-0.4,1.8-0.7c1.7-0.5,3.2-1.2,4.4-2.5c0.7-0.6,1.5-1,2.3-1.4
  c1-0.5,2.1-1,3.2-1.2c3.4-0.4,6.4-1.8,9.1-3.9c1-0.9,2.2-1.6,3.5-2c1.3-0.3,2.5-0.6,3.7-1.1c2.2-1.4-1-1.4-0.6-2.3
  c1-2.7,3.6-3.4,5.9-4.4c0.9-0.1,1.8,0,2.5,0.7c1.7,1.5,2.7-0.5,4-0.9c6.2-3.9,12.7-7.2,18.4-11.9
  C458.7,607.2,460,605.8,461.9,606.8z"/>
 <path id="XMLID_2483_" class="st6" d="M71.1,489.1c1,0.4,2,0.8,3,1.2c0.9,0.2,1.4,0.8,1.6,1.7c4.8,7.5,9.1,15.3,11.5,24
  c0.2,0.8,0.6,1.6,0.6,2.4c0.1,1.7,1.3,4.1-0.4,5.1c-1.9,1.1-2.9-1.4-4.2-2.5c-0.4-0.3-0.7-0.7-1.1-1c-1.7-1-2.6-2.5-3.5-4.2l0.1,0
  c-0.6-1.8-1.8-3.3-2.4-5c-1-1.6-1.5-3.4-2.8-4.7c-0.5-1.3-0.6-2.8-1.2-4c-0.4-0.9-0.8-1.8-1.2-2.7C70.3,495.8,70,492.4,71.1,489.1z
  "/>
 <path id="XMLID_2482_" class="st7" d="M403,161c-0.4-0.3-0.7-0.7-1.1-1c-1.7-0.8-3-2.4-5.1-1.9c-1.3,0.1-2.6-0.4-3.7,0.6
  c-1.2,1.5-2,0.6-2.7-0.5c-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.9-0.2-1.3c0-1.8-1.5-1.8-2.7-2.2c-1.8-0.6-3.5-1.2-5.2-2c-1-0.6-2.6-0.9-2.2-2.5
  c0.2-0.8,1.3-0.6,2-0.2c11.5,2.6,22.3,7.2,33,12c15.9,7,31,15.5,44.9,26.1c0.3,0.9-0.2,1.2-0.9,1.5c-1.2,0.1-2.2-0.2-3.4-0.4
  c-1.9-0.2-3.1-1.7-4.7-2.3c-1.5-0.8-3-1.8-4.3-3c-0.5-0.4-0.9-0.9-1.3-1.3c-0.9-1.1-2.2-1.8-3.6-2c-1.2-0.4-2.3-1.1-3.2-2.1
  c-0.8-1-1.8-1.8-3-2.3c-0.4-0.2-0.8-0.4-1.2-0.7c-2.2-1.7-4.7-2.8-7.4-3.7c-1-0.4-1.9-1.1-2.8-1.8c-1.3-1.3-3-1.6-4.7-1.8
  c-2.1-0.4-3.9-1.4-5.8-2.3c-2.4-1.6-5.4-1.5-7.7-3.2C405.1,161.9,403.9,161.7,403,161z"/>
 <path id="XMLID_2481_" class="st8" d="M478.1,596.2c-0.9-2-3,0-4.2-1.3c-0.4-1,0.1-1.7,0.8-2.4c1.2-0.9,2.5-1.8,4-2.1
  c1.6,0,2.7-1,3.7-2c1.1-1.1,2.2-2.2,3.2-3.3c2.6-2.9,5.7-5.2,8.2-8.2c1-1.3,2-2.6,3-3.8c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.2-0.6
  c2-2,4.3-3.8,6.1-6.1c1.3-1.8,2.6-3.5,4.2-5.1c1.5-1.6,2.6-3.5,4.1-5.1c1.7-2,3.2-4.2,4.8-6.3c0.7-1,1.4-2.1,1.9-3.3
  c0.2-0.4,0.4-0.7,0.7-1c1.6-0.3,2.4-1.5,3.2-2.7c-0.2-4,3-0.8,4.2-1.9C513.1,562,497.1,580.5,478.1,596.2z"/>
 <path id="XMLID_2480_" class="st9" d="M529.1,536.3c2-2.9-2.9-5.5-0.3-8.4c0.5,0.3,0.7,0.7,0.7,1.2c0.8-0.1,0.5-1,1-1.4
  c6.7-12.3,12.8-24.9,17.6-38c1.2-1.8,1.8-3.9,2.8-5.7c3.6,0.6,2.1-2.7,3-4c0.4-0.4,0.8-0.4,1.2,0.1c-5.1,18.2-13.3,35.1-22.8,51.4
  C531.4,533.1,530.2,534.7,529.1,536.3z"/>
 <path id="XMLID_2479_" class="st10" d="M566.1,415c1.5-1.5,0.7-3.3,0.9-5c-1.3-1.4-0.8-3.8-2.6-5c-0.2-0.5-0.3-1-0.4-1.5
  c-0.2-3.4,0.1-6.7,0.7-10.1c0.1-0.5,0.2-1,0.3-1.5c0.6-2.6,1.3-5.3,0.5-8c0-1.3-0.4-2.6,0.3-4.1c-1.2,2.5,0.7,4.9-0.6,7.1
  c-0.4,0.4-0.8,0.4-1.3,0.1c0,0-0.1,0-0.1,0c0.3-2.1-0.3-3.7-2-5c1.3-3.9,2.7-7.8,0.3-11.9c-0.5-1.4-0.8-2.9-1.1-4.3
  c-0.1-1.1,0-2.1,0.9-2.8c4.3-3.8,0.7-7.3-0.3-10.9c-1-0.1-1.3-0.5-0.6-1.4c0.8-0.4,1.5-0.3,2.1,0.2c3.2,12.7,4.1,25.8,4.6,38.8
  c0.5,11.1,0.3,22.3-0.9,33.3c-0.1,1,0.5,2.4-1,3c-0.2,0.1-0.5,0.2-0.7,0.3c-0.5-0.2-0.9-0.5-1.1-1c-0.6-1.8-0.6-3.6,0.3-5.3
  C565.4,418.5,564.4,416.3,566.1,415z"/>
 <path id="XMLID_2478_" class="st11" d="M458.8,189.1c0.4-0.3,0.8-0.7,1.2-1c14.9,10.3,28.2,22.2,40.1,35.8c0.5,1.1-0.1,1.8-0.9,2.4
  c-1,0.4-1.9,0-2.7-0.5c-1.4-0.9-2.2-2.3-3.2-3.7c-4.1-5.8-9.1-10.8-15.4-14.2c-0.9-0.3-1.7-0.8-2.3-1.6c-1.1-2.2-2.3-4.3-3.7-6.3
  c-0.5-0.3-1-0.6-1.5-0.9c-2.1,0.1-2.9-2.1-4.8-2.5c-1.1-0.3-1.8-1-2.4-1.9c-0.8-1.2-1.8-2.1-3.1-2.9c-0.4-0.2-0.7-0.5-0.9-0.9
  C458.8,190.3,458.6,189.8,458.8,189.1z"/>
 <path id="XMLID_2477_" class="st12" d="M565.1,426c0.3,0,0.7,0.1,1,0.1c0.1,13.8-3.1,27-6.8,40.1c-2-1.4-2.3-3.6-3-5.6
  c0.6-7.1,3-13.9,4-21c0.5-3.4-0.2-7,1.8-10.2C563,428.2,563.8,426.8,565.1,426z"/>
 <path id="XMLID_2476_" class="st13" d="M368,651c0.7,0.4,1.5,0.7,2.2,1.1c-15.3,4.3-31,6.5-46.9,7.1c-4.8,0.7-9.6,0.2-14.4,0.3
  c-0.7,0-1.1-0.3-1.2-1c0.3-1,1.1-1.3,2-1.5c1.7-0.4,3.4-0.2,5-0.3c0.5-0.1,1.1-0.1,1.6,0c3.5-0.2,6.9-1.3,10.5-0.9
  c2.6-0.1,5.2,0.3,7.8-0.5c1.5-0.4,3-0.4,4.5-0.5c0.5,0,0.9,0,1.4-0.1c2.1-0.6,4.5,0,6.4-1.5c0.8-1,1.9-1,3-0.8
  c1.6,0.5,3.1,0.3,4.7-0.3c3.7-1,7.4-2.1,11.4-2C366.8,650,367.5,650.3,368,651z"/>
 <path id="XMLID_2475_" class="st14" d="M221.3,155.1c0.7-0.1,1.5-0.2,2.2-0.3c0.9-0.5,1.9-0.9,3-0.9c1.1,0.1,2.1,0.3,2.6,1.4
  c0.2,1.2-0.5,1.9-1.2,2.6c-0.4,0.3-0.8,0.6-1.2,0.8c-2.4,0.8-4.6,1.9-6.9,3c-2.6,0.8-5,2.1-7.4,3.3c-1.9,0.9-3.7,1.8-5.5,2.7
  c-1.7,0.8-3.4,1.4-5.2,2c-1.4,0.4-2.7,1-4.1,1c-1.3-0.1-2.3-0.7-2.5-2.1c0.1-2.1,1.9-2.3,3.2-3.1c2.3-0.8,4.2-2.3,6.4-3.3
  c1.8-0.9,3.7-1.5,5.6-2.3c2-1,4-1.9,6-2.9C218.2,156.6,219.7,155.7,221.3,155.1z"/>
 <path id="XMLID_2474_" class="st15" d="M541,284c-0.4,0.4-0.7,0.8-1.1,1.1c-0.4,0.2-0.9,0.2-1.3-0.1c-1.1-1.2-1.5-2.8-2.5-4.1
  c-5.5-9.9-11.4-19.6-17.4-29.2c-0.9-1-1.5-2.2-2.2-3.4c-0.4-0.8-1.1-1.5-0.4-2.4c0.4-0.4,0.7-0.9,1.1-1.3
  C526.6,256.9,534.6,269.9,541,284z"/>
 <path id="XMLID_2472_" class="st16" d="M293,140c9.1-0.9,18.2-1.5,27.2-0.1c-3.5,2.9-7.9,0.5-11.7,2c-1.6,0.4-3.3,0.4-4.9,0.5
  c-1,0-2,0-3,0c-2-0.2-3.7,0.7-5.5,1.2c-0.5,0.1-1,0.1-1.5,0c-1.7-0.4-3.5-0.2-5.3-0.2c-3.9-0.3-7.7,0.9-11.6,1.4
  c-1.6,0.2-3.2,0.6-4.7-0.4c-0.6-0.8-0.6-1.6,0-2.3c1.4-0.2,2.6-1.3,4.1-0.8c1.7,0.5,3.3,0.8,4.9-0.3c1.6-1.2,3.4-0.8,5.1-0.7
  C288.4,140.6,290.7,140.9,293,140z"/>
 <path id="XMLID_2471_" class="st17" d="M134.1,586.9c2.6,3.5,7.3,5.3,8.3,10.1c-2.8,0.7-3.5-2.9-5.9-3c-0.5-0.4-0.9-0.8-1.4-1.2
  c-2.2-2.4-4.2-4.9-7-6.7c-0.7-0.8-1.4-1.5-2.1-2.3c-0.6-0.9-1.4-1.7-1.5-2.9c0.1-0.7,0.5-1.2,1.2-1.5c0.5-0.1,0.9-0.1,1.4,0
  c0.6,0.3,1.2,0.7,1.7,1.2C130.1,583.1,132.7,584.5,134.1,586.9z"/>
 <path id="XMLID_2470_" class="st18" d="M126.8,580.1c-0.3,0-0.6,0-0.8-0.1c-1.1-0.6-2.4-0.6-3.6-1.2c-0.4-0.1-0.8-0.3-1.1-0.6
  c-2.2-1.3-3.8-3.4-5.7-5.1c-1.1-0.4-0.7-1.4-1-2.2c1.4,0,2.7,0,4.1-0.1c0.8-0.4,1.3-1.5,2.4-1.2c3.3,2.4,6.4,4.9,8.3,8.6
  C129,579.6,128.5,580.7,126.8,580.1z"/>
 <path id="XMLID_2469_" class="st19" d="M260.8,655.1c-7.9-0.5-15.4-2.7-22.8-5.2c-0.2-0.9,0.4-1.3,1.1-1.6c0.7-0.2,1.4-0.3,2.2-0.3
  c1.9,0.3,3.7,0.8,5.6,1.1c0.9,0.2,1.8,0.6,2.7,0.9c1.7,0.9,3.6,0.8,5.4,1.1c1.2,0.2,2.3,0.6,3.5,0.7c1.3,0.1,2.6,0.2,3.6,1.1
  c0.5,0.7,0.5,1.5,0.1,2.3C261.8,655.4,261.3,655.5,260.8,655.1z"/>
 <path id="XMLID_2468_" class="st20" d="M336.4,140.9c7,0.2,13.9,1.4,20.8,3c0.3,1.5,4.5,0.4,2.3,3.5c-3.6,0.8-6.7-1.7-10.3-1.5
  c-1.3-0.3-2.5-0.7-3.8-1c-3-0.6-6.1-1.1-9.1-1.6c-1.4-0.2-3.5,0.1-3.2-2.5C334.2,140.4,335.3,140.5,336.4,140.9z"/>
 <path id="XMLID_2467_" class="st21" d="M293.8,659.1c-1.9-0.1-3.9-0.2-5.8-0.3c-2.1-0.8-4.4,0.1-6.5-0.7c-5.3,0-10.4-0.7-15.5-2.1
  c-0.5-0.5-0.6-1.1-0.4-1.8c0.2-0.4,0.6-0.6,1-0.7c0.4,0,0.9,0,1.3,0.1c1.8,0.4,3.5,0.2,5.3,0.3c0.7,0,1.4,0.2,2.1,0.4
  c2.5,0.6,5,1.6,7.7,1.5c1.2,0,2.4,0,3.6,0.1c0.7,0,1.4,0.2,2.1,0.4c1.4,0.5,2.8,0.6,4.2,0.7c0.7,0.1,1.4,0.3,2,0.8
  c0.3,0.4,0.3,0.9,0.2,1.4C294.7,659.4,294.2,659.4,293.8,659.1z"/>
 <path id="XMLID_2466_" class="st22" d="M83,273.9c-0.3,0.1-0.7,0.2-1,0.3c3.3-8.7,8.4-16.2,14-23.5c0.3,1.8-1.2,3-1.5,4.5
  c-1.1,5.8-5.6,9.8-7.8,14.9C85.5,271.4,84.9,273.3,83,273.9z"/>
 <path id="XMLID_2465_" class="st23" d="M382.1,149.9c-0.1,0.4-2.1-0.4-0.7,1c0.4,0.4,1.1,0.6,1.6,0.9c-0.4,1-1.2,1.4-2.2,1.6
  c-2.3-0.1-4.4-1.3-6.6-1.8c-1-0.5-1.9-1.2-2.8-1.8c-2-0.9-4-1.8-6.1-0.6c-0.5,0.1-0.9,0.2-1.4,0.1c-1.1-0.5-2.2-1-2.1-2.5
  c0.6-0.8,1.2-1.5,2.3-1C370.4,146.2,376.3,147.9,382.1,149.9z"/>
 <path id="XMLID_2464_" class="st24" d="M167.1,615.2c3.2-0.6,5.3,1.8,7.9,2.8c0.8,0.6,1.7,0.1,2.5,0.3c2.4,1.1,5.7,1.1,5.3,5.1
  c-1.5,1-3,1.5-4.8,0.6c-1-0.7-2-1.5-2.9-2.2c-1.1-0.9-2.3-1.8-3.6-2.4c-1.4-1.4-3.1-2.1-4.8-2.9l0.1-0.1
  C166.5,615.9,166.6,615.5,167.1,615.2z"/>
 <path id="XMLID_2463_" class="st25" d="M557.1,461c1.5,1.4,1.8,3.3,2.1,5.2c0,0,0,0,0,0c-1.9,1-0.1,3-1.1,4.2
  c-0.3,3.4-1.4,6.6-2.9,9.7c-0.4,0-0.8,0-1.2-0.1c0.9-2.4,1.8-4.9,2.6-7.3c0.7-2.1,0.3-3.8-1.9-4.8
  C553.7,464.9,554.3,462.6,557.1,461z"/>
 <path id="XMLID_2462_" class="st26" d="M50.9,387c-1.6,4.3-0.3,8.8-0.8,13.2c-0.2,2.3,0.7,4.7-0.9,6.7c0.2-9.7-0.9-19.3,0.9-28.9
  c2.1,0.1,1.9,1.9,2.2,3.2C52.3,383.3,52.7,385.4,50.9,387z"/>
 <path id="XMLID_2461_" class="st27" d="M185.1,172.2c0.3,1-3.8,1.9-0.1,3c-0.6,2.9-3.2,2.7-5.3,3.3c-1.1,0-2.1-0.3-3.2-0.7
  c-0.4-0.2-0.7-0.5-0.9-0.8c1.7-3.4,5.4-4.2,8.3-6C184.7,171.1,185.1,171.5,185.1,172.2z"/>
 <path id="XMLID_2460_" class="st28" d="M237,149.2c0.3,0,0.7-0.1,1-0.1c2,0.9,5.3-1.2,6.2,2.5c-2.6,3.6-6.7,4-10.6,4.9
  c-0.7-0.1-1.3-0.5-1.7-1.1c-0.3-0.7-0.1-1.3,0.4-1.8c0.9-0.8,2.1-1.2,2.8-2.2C235.6,150.5,236.2,149.8,237,149.2z"/>
 <path id="XMLID_2459_" class="st29" d="M214.9,642c-3.8-0.9-7.3-2.6-10.9-4.3c-0.1-0.8,0.4-1.3,1-1.6c2.3-1.4,4.8-0.5,7.3-0.5
  c1.9,0.3-0.3,3.2,2,3.2C214.7,639.8,217.6,640.5,214.9,642z"/>
    </svg>
```

Все получилось спасибо Qwertiy
http://jsfiddle.net/sLtu7zag/3/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sLtu7zag/4/

Comment: Что-то так себе выглядит. Какие-то лишние пятна местами...

Comment: Qwertiy это уже мелочи, для меня главное было понять суть как это сделать а остальное поправится! Спасибо за помощь!